# mysql: узнать время последней записи (последнего изменения) в таблицу

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select

Подскажите, как узнать время самой последней записи в таблицу? Записи, удаления, изменения и т.д., но не получения данных!!!

Когда делаю такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UPDATE_TIME) as last_update 
FROM 
    information_schema.tables 
WHERE 
    UPDATE_TIME IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 
    UPDATE_TIME DESC, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
LIMIT 
    1, 1;
```

то получаю именно время обращение к таблице, поэтому каждый раз запрос будет выдавать новое время (по сути время выполнения этого запроса)

А как получить именно время изменения в таблице?

Comment: *получаю именно время обращение к таблице* Какой движок у таблицы?

Comment: @Akina, движок - InnoDB

Comment: Таблица - партиционированная? создавалась при `innodb_file_per_table = ON`? покажите для неё выборки из INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TABLESPACES и INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_DATAFILES.

Comment: PS. `information_schema.tables.UPDATE_TIME` возвращает время обновления ФАЙЛА в котором хранятся данные указанной таблицы, да ещё с кучей ограничений. Если таблица лежит в SYSTEM tablespace, который дёргается сервером практически безостановочно - то неудивительно, что ни хрена не получается.

Comment: PPS. Когда нужно получать штамп времени последнего обновления, в структуру вводят автообновляемое поле штампа времени, и тупо потом берут максимальное значение по этому полю.

Comment: @Akina, `Когда нужно получать штамп времени последнего обновления, в структуру вводят автообновляемое поле штампа времени, и тупо потом берут максимальное значение по этому полю` - т.е.в нужные таблицы специально внедряют автообновляемое поле для этих целей?

Comment: Да. Хотя не только для этого - время создания/обновления записи зачастую важно само по себе. Альтернативно - создаётся служебная таблица, хранящая имя и штамп времени, и на каждую рабочую таблицу вешается триггер, который по факту изменения апдейтит запись в служебной для изменяемой таблицы.

Comment: @Akina, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TABLESPACES и INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_DATAFILES` - такое отсутствует, а `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLESPACES` - пустое (записей нет)

Comment: Значит, `innodb_file_per_table = OFF`. UPDATE_TIME в таком случае ниачём.